# Jquery Use Row of Table Populated By PHP in Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, triggers

was hoping to have someone with jQuery expertise help me out here...

I have a table that is created dynamically through php using such code:

```
...
  <tbody>
<?php
foreach ($members as $member){
  echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td><a href='#' class='edituser-information' title='edituser_information' data-id=" .$member['id']. "><img src='/images/edit-button.png' width='59' height='28' alt='EDIT'></a>";
  echo '</tr>';
}?>
  </tbody>
...
```

I am passing information into a jQuery function and then ajax using this:

```
$('#editUsersTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (){           
  data_id = $('td a.edituser-information', this).eq(0).attr('data-id');
  $.ajax({
   url: 'edit_specific_user.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {id : data_id},
   ...
```

#### THE PROBLEM:

The ajax script picks up data-id correctly because it loads the information right through the row that was clicked on...  Unfortunately, what I want is the user is FORCED to click the edit button, and not just the row in the table...

As of now, the user can just click the row, and then it proceeds right into the jQuery because the `entire row` is the trigger.

How can I change it that the user must click the specific row's edit button, and not the row itself?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Forced is not well..
you can try focus on the button. use focus()

Comment: sorry, I mean user must click the edit button to proceed to ajax script... not just click on row to proceed to ajax script

Comment: change this: on('click', 'tr',

Comment: you trigger on tbody /*$('#editUsersTable tbody')*/, change it to  edit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('#editUsersTable tbody tr td').on('click', 'a.edituser-information', function (){           
    data_id = $(this).eq(0).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
    url: 'edit_specific_user.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {id : data_id},
    ...
```

Comment: Wow...  Maybe I need more coffee.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the propogation selector in the very first line:

```
$('#editUsersTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (){
```

changes to

```
$('#editUsersTable tbody').on('click', 'tr a', function (){
```

Refer to the "Direct and Delegated events" section in the jQuery documentation for "on"

http://api.jquery.com/on/